# How to convert system generated logs to image using Python?

Tags: python, security, image-processing, logging

I have system generated logs in CEF format from Archsight.

```
CEF:0|ArcSight|ArcSight|6.0.3.6664.0|agent:030|Agent [test] type [testalertng] started|Low| 
eventId=1 mrt=1396328238973 categorySignificance=/Normal categoryBehavior=/Execute/Start 
categoryDeviceGroup=/Application catdt=Security Mangement categoryOutcome=/Success 
categoryObject=/Host/Application/Service art=1396328241038 cat=/Agent/Started 
deviceSeverity=Warning rt=1396328238937 fileType=Agent 
cs2=<Resource ID\="3DxKlG0UBABCAA0cXXAZIwA\=\="/> c6a4=fe80:0:0:0:495d:cc3c:db1a:de71 
cs2Label=Configuration Resource c6a4Label=Agent 
IPv6 Address ahost=SKEELES10 agt=888.99.100.1 agentZoneURI=/All Zones/ArcSight 
System/Private Address Space 
Zones/RFC1918: 888.99.0.0-888.200.255.255 av=6.0.3.6664.0 atz=Australia/Sydney 
aid=3DxKlG0UBABCAA0cXXAZIwA\=\= at=testalertng dvchost=SKEELES10 dvc=888.99.100.1 
deviceZoneURI=/All Zones/ArcSight System/Private Address Space Zones/RFC1918: 
888.99.0.0-888.200.255.255 dtz=Australia/Sydney _cefVer=0.1
```

I need to convert the CEF file into a image either by considering all the fields in it or considering only some specific field like *categoryBehavior*, *deviceSeverity*, *av*, *atz*, *deviceZoneURI* (these are only examples where i will consider these field to analyse abnormal behavior in a particular or a sequence of logs).

For further info about CEF format and how it is generated from RAW logs please refer this [link](https://kc.mcafee.com/resources/sites/MCAFEE/content/live/CORP_KNOWLEDGEBASE/78000/KB78712/en_US/CEF_White_Paper_20100722.pdf)

**I would like to get a image for a sequence of logs in 24 hrs where each field is one image itself with size 24x60 (each hour will be one row of the image).**

If you have some other good approach to convert CEF files or event logs please include in your answer.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid this is too broad for a question; there are many possible implementations, from using Grafana to coding your own solution from scratch with logs parsing and `matplotlib` or `bokeh` or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for your time @hoefling. please let me know if you need any specific clarification apart from the question i have posted.

Answer (score 0):

For each user for a particular time-frame (say 1 min) extract the variables you need. for each variable convert the values into a vector(if its not a number). plot the variable in such a way that y axis will have 24 hours and x axis will have 60 minutes. which will give you each pixel intensity as activity of that user for one minute.
plot the same for all variables, you will have depth of the image (channels) as number of variables you have extracted.

Please comment if anyone has a better approach.
Thanks in advance